# Swift 4.2 closures

Tags: swift, closures

Hi I'm learning swift I have an exercise on closures used to filter collections

I have two simple closures that are used to filter and map a dictionary

```
let myDict: [String: Int] = ["Dan":38, "Kira":2, "Olga":33, "Jess":10, "Bobo":4]

let filteredMyDict = myDict.filter {
    return $0.value < 5
}
print(filteredMyDict)

let filteredNames = filteredMyDict.map {
    return $0.key
}

print(filteredNames)
```

Is it possible to chain the filter and map statement , if so how.

That

Comment: `let filteredNames = myDict.filter({ $0.value < 5 }).map({ $0.key })`?. Not that the `return` are not needed, but I agree that since you are learning, making them explicit is good for your current level of comprehension.
Maybe another solution (not tested): `let filteredNames = myDict.flatMap({ if 0.value < 5 { return $0.key } else { return nil }})`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can chain `filter` and `map`

```
let filteredNames = myDict.filter { $0.value < 5 }
    .map { $0.key }
```

or use [`compactMap`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2950916-compactmap) to get the result with a single traversal of the
dictionary:

> Returns an array containing the non-nil results of calling the given transformation with each element of this sequence.

In your case:

```
let filteredNames = myDict.compactMap {
    $0.value < 5 ? $0.key : nil
}
```